# Why does this Nhibernate query return an empty list?

Tags: nhibernate

Why wouldn't this query work it always returns a empty list (Mapping is ok and i m sure the database has the data !) any ideas ?

```
var ids = //IList<int> of ids 


var result = _session.CreateCriteria(typeof (User))
            .Add(Restrictions.InG("Id", ids))
            .CreateCriteria("Posts")
            .AddOrder(Order.Asc("CreatedOn"))
            .SetMaxResults(20)
           .List<Post>();
```

Comment: You are asking for a type of User and then ending the query with a return of a List of Posts. Otherwise I'm not sure? I usually don't use the CreateCriteria syntax for these types of data access methods

Comment: @mikeschuld : I do have .CreateCriteria("Posts") so i can ask for a list of posts

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well i just used HQL instead of the criteria api :

```
var result = _session.CreateQuery("from Post p order by p.CreatedOn where p.PostedBy.Id IN (" + sb + ")").List<Post>();
```

everything works just fine :)

Comment: Cool. Glad one of the three options could work out for you! :)

Answer (score 5):

Try using something like this instead:

```
List<User> users = _session.CreateQuery("FROM User ORDER BY CreatedOn").List<User>().Where(u => ids.Contains(u.Id));

var posts = new List<Post>();
foreach(User user in users) {
    posts.AddRange(user.Posts);
}
```

I guess that would depend on your User already having a Posts collection, but most hibernate implementations should have something like that in there.

You could also compact it a bit like this:

```
List<Post> posts = _session.CreateQuery("FROM Post ORDER BY CreatedOn").List<Post>().Where(p => ids.Contains(p.User.Id));
```

OR a third option:

```
List<Post> posts = _session.CreateQuery("FROM Post ORDER BY CreatedOn WHERE User.Id IN (" + ids.ToArray().Join(",") + ")").List<Post>();
```

Comment: This is not good user might have thousands of posts i don't want to get them from database and sort them sort them in memory !

Comment: @Yassir see the third option. It should only grab the correct set and not the thousands of unneeded ones.

Comment: Well createdon property is a post property not a user property :)

Comment: Well you still get the idea ;)